# Qt Thread event-loop does not dispatch self created signals

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qobject

I wand to create a GUI-Application that communicates with a device connected to my PC. Therefore I want to split the GUI handling from the device communication to different threads to avoid blocking of the GUI (One Controller thread and one GUI-Thread). I already did that with PyQt5 in Python. Since I now want to create an application in C++ I programmed it the same way as I would do it in PyQt. But the result is not the same. The communication between the threads shall be handled by the signal and slot system of Qt which should be thread-safe. So I create my GUI-object (inherits QWidget class) and my Controller-Object(inherits QObject) and I create an instance of QThread, connect the signals and slots of gui and controller objects, move the controller object to the new created thread, start the thread and then execute the QApplication object. I now have the problem that events that are created by Qt-Objects (i.e. QPushButton) where handled by the controller thread but self created signals not (emit). Here is the important part of my code:

GUI.h:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/qwidget.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qcombobox.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qlayout.h>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

class myGUI : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   myGUI(QWidget * parent=nullptr);
   virtual ~myGUI() = default;
   void load_settings();
signals:
   void refreshPorts(void);
   void connect(std::string port);
public slots:
   void onPortsRefreshed(std::deque<std::string> port_list);
protected:
   QHBoxLayout * hbox;
   QPushButton * refresh_ports_btn;
   QPushButton * connect_btn;
   QComboBox *   port_cbx;

   void on_connect_pressed();
}
```

GUI.cpp:

```cpp
#include "GUI.h"

myGUI::myGUI(QWidget * parent)
   : QWidget(parent)
{
   this->hbox = new QHBoxLayout;
   this->port_cbx = new QComboBox;
   this->refresh_ports_btn = new QPushButton("Refresh ports");
   this->connect_btn = new QPushButton("connect");
   this->hbox->addWidget(this->port_cbx);
   this->hbox->addWidget(this->refresh_ports_btn);

   this->setLayout(this->hbox);

   /* connecting the signals and slots */
   QObject::connect(this->refresh_ports_btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &myGUI::refreshPorts);
   QObject::connect(this->connect_btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &myGUI::on_connect_pressed);
}

void myGUI::load_settings()
{
   emit this->refreshPorts();
}

void myGUI::on_connect_pressed()
{
   std::string port = this->port_cbx->currentText().toStdString();
   if(!port.empty())
   {
      emit this->connect(port);
   }
}

void myGUI::onPortsRefreshed(std::deque<std::string> port_list)
{
   this->port_cbx.clear();
   for(auto &elem : port_list)
   {
      this->port_cbx->addText(QString::fromStdString(elem));
   }
}
```

Controller.h:

```cpp
#include <QtCore/qobject.h>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

class myController : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   myController(QObject * parent = nullptr);
   virtual ~myController() = default;

signals:
   void ports_refreshed(std::deque<std::string> );

public slots:
   void on_refresh_ports(void);
   void on_connect(void);
}
```

Controller.cpp

```cpp
#include "Controller.h"

myController::myController(QObject * parent)
   : QObject(parent)
{

}

void myController::on_refresh_ports()
{
   auto port_list = std::deque<std::string>();
   port_list.push_back(std::string("COM1"));
   port_list.push_back(std::string("COM4"));
   emit this->ports_refreshed(port_list);
}

void myController::on_connect(std::string port)
{
   /* connect to com-port */
}
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "GUI.h"
#include "Controller.h"
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <QtCore/qthread.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   myGUI * gui = new myGUI;
   myController * ctrl = new Controller;
   QTread ctrl_thrd = new QThread;

   QObject::connect(gui, &myGUI::refreshPorts, ctrl, &myController::on_refresh_ports);
   QObject::connect(gui, &myGUI::connect, ctrl, &myController::on_connect);
   QObject::connect(ctrl, &myController::ports_refreshed, gui, &myGUI::onPortsRefreshed);

   ctrl_thrd->start();
   ctrl->moveToThread(ctrl_trhd);

   gui->load_settings();

   gui->show();

   return app.exec();
}
```

The application starts but the method refresh_ports is never called (neither when load_settings is called nor when I click on "Refresh-Ports". The behavior is different when I directly connect the "clicked" event of QPushButtons with the slot of the Controller object. When I remove the ctrl_thrd and just run it in a single thread the application works fine.
I did a lot of research about my problem on other questions but did not find an answer. (Most was about the wrong usage of QThread when inherit from it and not moving the object to the thread).
Code like this always worked in PyQt. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: code for object deletion was left out of the example.

Comment: You should register custom types (e.g. std::string and std::deque) in Qt meta types system to be able to use them in signal/slots between different threads.

Comment: So just adding qRegisterMetaType<std::string>(); and qRegisterMetaType<std::deque<std::string>>(); ?

Comment: Yes, or use Qt types.

Comment: I added Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::string) and Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::deque<std::string>) since qRegisterMetaType<std::string>(); made a compiler error. It did not fix the problem :-(

Comment: #define Q_REGISTER_MY_METATYPE(type) qRegisterMyMetaType<type>(#type);

Comment: And use e.g. Q_REGISTER_MY_METATYPE(std::string). And yes, you need to use both Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and Q_REGISTER_MY_METATYPE.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed all my problems. How can I mark your comment as the correct answer?